# JSTree space between nodes

Tags: jstree

I have a nasty problem with JSTree JQuery Plug in and Css.

Due to the fact my web application has its css (that I cannot change) over the JStree's css, now the tree view has strange spaces beetween nodes as shown in the screen shot that I have attached (please look at red circle) and these spaces shoud not be here like the original plug-in is.

Could someone give me a Css solution for that? Thank you in advance.

screen-shot:

[image]

Comment: How go you populate your tree? Usually you do this either with HTML or JSON data which you can 1) encode in your page statically or 2) receive from server and add programmatically. Which is your way and how does this data look like?

Comment: Nikolay thanks anyway, now I checked out JS Fiddle and I solved the problem ! cheers :)

Comment: Will you then accept my answer? Please click on the checkmark next to it. You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a new CSS class with margins set to 0 and attaching it to your jsTree nodes when initializing jsTree. Do it by passing a `li_attr` to the tree config like this:

```
var data = [
 { "id": "root2", ..., "li_attr": { "class": "smaller-margins" } } 
]
```

See demo - [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/atzy4qxd/)